When does the normality of $T^3$ imply that of $T^2$, where $T\in B(H)$?
Let $T\in B(H)$. Assume that $T^3$ is normal, i.e., $T^{*3}T^3=T^3T^{*3}$. When is $T^2$ normal?
Here is a known related result, which may be more or less trivial:
If $T^2$ is normal and $T$ has a positive real part, then $T$ is normal.
Feel free to share any ideas or insights.
